# How to switch en as the default language keyboard after login?

Tags: keyboard-layout

[image]

**th** is always the default keyboard language after login. Can you please teach me how to set the default keyboard language to **en** instead and as shown above ?

Comment: If *English (US)* is the active layout when you log out, it should keep being so when you log in, i.e. the system remembers the active layout at logout. Does it work differently on your machine?

Comment: Dear @Gunnar,
It is as your comment. It did remember the active layout at logout.